# how to use PHP loop in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have the following JQuery Function.

```
   <script>

    var forbiddenWords = ['Phone', 'Home', 'Address', 'Number', 'Postcode', 'email', 'call','n u m b e r'];
    $(function () {
      $('.msgbox').on('keyup', function(e) {
        forbiddenWords.forEach(function(val, index) {
          if (e.target.value.toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
              e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(new RegExp( "(" + val + ")" , 'gi' ), '');
          }
        });
      });
    });

    </script>
```

I want the words in fordiddenWords array should be dynamic and must come from MySQL database. I have written the following code but it is not working..!

```
     <script>

 var forbiddenWords = [<?php foreach($result as $res) { echo $res->rest_words; } ?>];
        $(function () {
          $('.msgbox').on('keyup', function(e) {
            forbiddenWords.forEach(function(val, index) {
              if (e.target.value.toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
                  e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(new RegExp( "(" + val + ")" , 'gi' ), '');
              }
            });
          });
        });

        </script>
```

The words appear like this..!

> var forbiddenWords = [phonenumberaddress];

Please Help.

Comment: Check your console for error

Comment: can you console.log this variable forbiddenWords ?

Comment: $res->rest_words is array of words ? or a single string ?

Comment: No, you don't need Ajax for this

Comment: Use the `|` operator of regex to avoid the for loop : `value.replace(/word1|word2|word3/gi,'')`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use json_encode function for convert php array into JSON/Javascript object or Array

```
var forbiddenWords = [<?php foreach($result as $res) { echo $res->rest_words; } ?>];
```

Replace it with

```
<?php
$arr=array();
foreach($result as $res) { $arr[]=$res->rest_words; }
?>
var forbiddenWords = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
```

OR

```
var forbiddenWords = <?php echo json_encode(array_map(function($record){ return $record->rest_words; }, $result)); ?>;
```

Comment: you can check my edits for what was missing http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38721777/revisions

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the commas and the quotes:

```
 <script>

 var forbiddenWordsString = <?php foreach($result as $res) { echo "'" . $res->rest_words . "',"; } ?>;
 var forbiddenWords = [forbiddenWords.substring(0, str.length - 1)]; // remove last comma
    $(function () {
      $('.msgbox').on('keyup', function(e) {
        forbiddenWords.forEach(function(val, index) {
          if (e.target.value.toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
              e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(new RegExp( "(" + val + ")" , 'gi' ), '');
          }
        });
      });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: syntax error: trailing comma after last array element

Answer (score 0):

Echoing like this directly in Javascript is not the correct way to pass information. It would be easier if you convert your $result array to json so it's more native for js. Try:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

So it should look something like this:

```
var forbiddenWords = <?=json_encode($result)?>;
```

Comment: Will produce array of objects. `$result` needs to be mapped first to expected output structure

Comment: var forbiddenWords = [{"rest_word":"phone"},{"rest_word":"number"},{"rest_word":"address"}];

Comment: Yes, as @charlietfl mentioned and as I missed to write you should map the result. Try var result = forbiddenWords.map(function(a) {return a.rest_word;}); and then result should be mapped array